# Dynamic query results to array in php5

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic

So I have a function that handles queries:

```
function cfquery($query){
    // Connection's Parameters
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_name="d";
    $username="u";
    $password="p";
    $db_con=mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
    $connection_string=mysql_select_db($db_name);
    // Connection
    mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);

    // Query
    $sql = $query;
    $results = mysql_query($sql);
    return $results; 
}
```

And I'm trying to write a function that will take the results and put them into an array, but this function is generating a 'resource', and everything I'm finding on the internet doesn't work for that data type, or isn't generated dynamically - like you have to know the column names in order to get to the data.

For instance:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    echo $row['name'] . ',' ;
    echo $row['email'] . ',' ;
    echo $row['city'] . ',' ;
}
```

I'm looking for something that will get the column names from the results. Like this:

```
$array = new array();
loop rows index x {
    loop column_names index y {
        $array[x][y] = $results[rows][column_names];
    }
}
```

If you can't tell, I'm transitioning from ColdFusion, so I have only a vague idea of what a "resource" is (after reading some documentation), and no idea why I can't get an array out of it.

Comment: It is **not** recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future. See [MySQL: Choosing an API](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 2):

**If you can use MySQLi:** Use [`mysqli_fetch_field_direct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php) to get field metadata.

The field name can be accessed like so (within your results loop):

```
$metadata = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($row, $field_index);
$name = $metadata->name;
```

**If you are stuck using the deprecated (as of 5.5) `mysql` functions:**  then you can use `mysql_field_name($result, $field_index)` instead in the same manner although it will directly return the name as a string and not an object.

You can read up on MySQLi and it's implementation here: https://www.php.net/mysqli

Answer (score 0):

**mysql_* is deprecated... use mysqli_* or pdo**

In MySQL...

```
function cfquery($query)
{
    $return = array();

    $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","u","p") or die('connection error');
    mysql_select_db("d", $cn) or die('select db error');

    $results = mysql_query($query, $cn) or die(mysql_error($cn));

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) )
        $return[] = $row;

    mysql_free_result($results);
    mysql_close($cn);

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You used the deprecated functions in your answer.

Comment: User use mysql_* function... I have warned

Comment: Your top comment makes it sound like you hadn't. I'd explicitly state that your example uses the deprecated functions to prevent confusion.